# Number of users that logged in at least once in past 7 days, day by day

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I want to get a number of users that logged at least once in past week, but I want it to be calculated for each day independently, so grouping it by week number won't work.

My `crm_login_info` table structure looks like that:

```
user_id (INT) | login_time (DATETIME)
            1 | 2017-08-10 14:32:25
            2 | 2017-08-11 14:32:25
            3 | 2017-08-11 14:32:25
            2 | 2017-08-13 14:32:25
            3 | 2017-08-14 14:32:25
            4 | 2017-08-15 14:32:25
            5 | 2017-08-15 14:32:25
            2 | 2017-08-18 14:32:25
            1 | 2017-08-19 14:32:25
            3 | 2017-08-20 14:32:25
            5 | 2017-08-20 14:32:25
            2 | 2017-08-21 14:32:25
            3 | 2017-08-22 14:32:25
```

I've got 2 indexes - one is on pair `user_id` and `login_time` and second is `login_time` only.

What I'm trying to achieve is function, which for above set of data would output something along these lines:

```
2017-08-10 | 1
2017-08-11 | 3
2017-08-12 | 3
2017-08-13 | 3
2017-08-14 | 3
2017-08-15 | 5
2017-08-16 | 5
2017-08-17 | 4
2017-08-18 | 4
2017-08-19 | 5
2017-08-20 | 5
2017-08-21 | 5
2017-08-22 | 4
```

I already came up with a query that is supposed to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(`login_time`,'%Y-%m-%d')) AS date1, (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`)
FROM crm_login_info
WHERE `login_time` > DATE_SUB(date1, INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND `login_time` <=  
DATE_ADD(date1, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS distinct1
FROM crm_login_info
ORDER BY date1 ASC
```

but first of all, it is giving me warnings about using `date1` in lower queries, and second is that when I run `EXPLAIN` before this whole query it tells me that subquery `distinct1` doesn't use any indexes and I'm afraid that it would run very long since it's pretty big table (~7m rows) and to be fair I couldn't get that query to finish even with cutting off data with `WHERE login_time > '2017-08-28'`.

While I know I could just split it up in hundreds of queries (one for each day) and save it somewhere because past data won't change, I'm looking for some more dynamic solution because I don't want to further increase complexity of my system by adding another file/table in db just for single stat.

I've looked for solution online already, but couldn't find anything that would be helpful in my case. Thank you for any help you can provide and feel free to ask via comment if you need further clarification.

EDIT: I want that data to be generated for past days, day by day, for at least past year. Also, for further clarification, I want number of **distinct users** logged in past 7 days, not amount of logins, and I want it to generate it for past days as well, for example for date `2017-08-22` it would calculate distinct `user_id`s from range `2017-08-16` to `2017-08-22` including those dates.

Comment: Please clarify: In past week or in past year?

Comment: Number of users logged in in past 7 days, day by day, generated for days since at least year ago

Comment: to be honest this (to me) does not seems like job for mysql (or other query languages). I would just get the results for query as in @Pharaoh answer, and then just count the desired results from the result of this query -- its just a simple loop in any programming langage.

Comment: @Drecker That won't work because when I (as the single user of the website) am online every day, that calculation will result in 7 - while the actual result should be 1. I don't think this is doable without a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `GROUP BY` query?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(login_time, '%Y-%m-%d') date1, count(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM login_info
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE(login_time)
ORDER BY date1 DESC
```

Comment: Wouldn't it count user that logged every day as 7 instead of 1? Also, what about days before week ago?

Comment: Eh? there shoud be `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)` instead of `COUNT(*)` but otherwise I believe this query shoud work fine. (It most certainly wont count user who logged every day as 7 since this counts only over aggregated rows)

Comment: @Drecker OP wants to count "the visits of the past 7 days" for each day, not the visits this day. The remark about `DISTINCT` is correct nonetheless, I changed that.